# TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type in flask

Tags: python, numpy

[i need some one to help me on this flask project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f48Op.png)

i 'm doing a classification program that classifies Alzheimer's and i need to solve this problem in line 82 and line 87

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Get the image from post request
    img = base64_to_pil(request.json)

    # Save the image to ./uploads
    img.save("image.png")
    image_width, image_height = 224, 224
    img = image.load_img("image.png", target_size=(image_width, image_height))
    # Make prediction
    classes = {'MildDemented': 0,'ModerateDemented': 1,'NonDemented': 2,'VeryMildDemented': 3}
    new_dict = {value:key for (key,value) in classes.items()}
    preds = new_dict[np.argmax(model_predict(img))]

    # Process your result for human
    pred_proba = "{:.3f}".format(np.amax(preds))    # Max probability
    result = str(preds)              # Convert to string
    # result = result.replace('_', ' ').capitalize()
    
    # Serialize the result, you can add additional fields
    return jsonify(result=result, probability=pred_proba)

return None
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gouda\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gouda\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\gouda\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\gouda\myenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "c:/Users/gouda/Desktop/graduation project/keras-flask-deploy-webapp-master/app.py", line 82, in predict
    pred_proba = float("{:.3f}".format(np.max(preds)))    # Max probability
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in amax
  File "C:\Users\gouda\myenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2705, in amax
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
  File "C:\Users\gouda\myenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 87, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
127.0.0.1 - - [2021-12-18 02:02:39] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 426 3.283108
```

Comment: You've made it as far as `pred_proba`, so `image.png` is probably a valid image. If it isn't, you have a flask-related problem. If it is, you have might have a keras-related problem. In that case, drop the flask tags from your question and add keras, so that your problem will get in front of the right people.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the traceback, I see that the error occurs at:

```
pred_proba = float("{:.3f}".format(np.max(preds)))    # Max probability
```

That's the traceback line that is the clearest match to the posted code.  Working back from there, I can reproduce the error with:

```
In [785]: classes = {'MildDemented': 0,'ModerateDemented': 1,'NonDemented': 2,'V
     ...: eryMildDemented': 3}
     ...: new_dict = {value:key for (key,value) in classes.items()}
In [786]: new_dict
Out[786]: 
{0: 'MildDemented',
 1: 'ModerateDemented',
 2: 'NonDemented',
 3: 'VeryMildDemented'}
In [787]: new_dict[1]
Out[787]: 'ModerateDemented'
In [788]: np.amax(new_dict[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-788-776c7a8af82b>", line 1, in <module>
    np.amax(new_dict[1])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in amax
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2754, in amax
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 86, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

In other words, you are trying to apply `np.amax` to array containing one string.  Max on string doesn't make sense!